# Error propagation in recurrence relation

Tags: numerical-analysis, precision

I have a recurrence relation

$$P_{n} = A_{n} P_{n-1} - B_{n}P_{n-2}$$

with given $P_{0}$ and $P_{1}$.

Numerically, each $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ is calculated with some precision. The same applies to the $P_{0}$ and $P_{1}$. How can one estimates the error for the $n$-th term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good reference for this is *Error Bounds for Linear Recurrence Relations* by F. W. J. Olver (Mathematics of Computation, 1988).

At the most basic level, you can examine the sensitivity of $P_n$ to changes in $A_m,B_m$. So
$$ P_n+\delta P_n = (A_n+\delta A_n)(P_{n-1}+\delta P_{n-1}) - (B_n + \delta B_n)(P_{n-2} + \delta P_{n-2}), $$
which to first order leads to the recurrences
$$ P_n = A_nP_{n-1} - B_n P_{n-2}, $$
$$ \delta P_n = A_n \delta P_{n-1} - B_n \delta P_{n-2} + (\delta A_n P_{n-1} - \delta B_n P_{n-2}). $$
As you can see, the error terms satisfy the same recurrence relation, but with an extra inhomogeneous term that depends on the errors in $A_n,B_n$.

If you can find a general solution to the inhomogeneous recurrence relation, and also put a bound on the inhomogeneous term, that would give you a bound on the errors in $P_n$. This is analogous to how truncation error of a finite difference method for ODEs is converted into a bound on the method's global error. This also usually goes by the name of forward-mode sensitivity analysis.

One issue here is that often the errors in $A_n,B_n$ are not independent, and this analysis can be overly conservative; a similar issue can arise with using interval arithmetic to analyse roundoff errors in the recurrence relation. Olver's paper shows how to get rigorous bounds.